# Matrix of a linear map from $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ and inverse map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be inear map from $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $$f\left(\begin{matrix}
  x & y \\
  z & t
 \end{matrix}\right) = (x+t, z-y).$$
How can I find the matrix of $f$ with respect to the basis  $\begin{pmatrix}   1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}$ of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and to the basis $(1,0), (0,1)$ of $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Also, given a vector subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R^2}$, for example the one spanned by $(1,1)$ or the one spanned by $(2,1)$, how can I find a basis of $f^{-1}(W)$?

Comment: You should just think of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ as $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: You don't have to use any properties of matrices (like the fact that they are linear maps themselves) here. The question is basically asking about the linear map $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $(x,y,z,t) \mapsto (x+t,z-y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4$ denote the basis elements
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0},
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},
\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0},
\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}
$$
respectively.  Let $v_1 = (1,0)$ and $v_2 = (0,1)$.

We note that
$$
f(u_1) = \color{red}1 \cdot v_1 + \color{blue}0 \cdot v_2\\
f(u_2) = \color{red}0 \cdot v_1 + \color{blue}{(-1)}\cdot v_2\\
f(u_3) = \color{red}0 \cdot v_1 + \color{blue}1 \cdot v_2\\
f(u_4) = \color{red}1 \cdot v_1 + \color{blue}0 \cdot v_2
$$
Thus, the matrix of $f$ with respect to the bases $\{u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4\}$ and $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is given by
$$
\pmatrix{
\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&\color{red}1\\
\color{blue}0&\color{blue}{-1}&\color{blue}1&\color{blue}0}
$$

---

The space $f^{-1}[\text{span}(1,1)]$ is the sum of the spaces $f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ and the span of any single vector in $f^{-1}[(1,1)]$

To find $f^{-1}(0)$ and $f^{-1}[(1,1)]$, we row reduce:
$$
\pmatrix{
1&0&0&1&|&1\\
0&-1&1&0&|&1
} \to
\pmatrix{
1&0&0 &1&|&1\\
0&1&-1&0&|&-1
}
$$
We conclude that the vectors 
$$
\pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\-1} = v_1 - v_4, \pmatrix{0\\1\\1\\0} = v_2 + v_3
$$
form a basis of $f^{-1}[\{0\}]$.

Moreover, we note that 
$$
f\pmatrix{1\\-1\\0\\0} = f(v_1 - v_2) = (1,1)
$$
So, the vectors $\{v_1-v_4,v_2+v_3,v_1-v_2\}$ form a basis of $f^{-1}[\text{span}[(1,1)]]$.

Comment: Why "the space $f^{-1}[\text{span}(1,1)]$ is the sum of the spaces $f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ and the span of any single vector in $f^{-1}[(1,1)]$"?

Comment: And also, why to find $f^{-1}(0)$ and $f^{-1}[(1,1)]$, we row reduce that matrix. In short, could you explain in more detail the second part of the exercise?

Comment: @mathlearner how would you solve the equations $f(x) = 0$, and $f(x) = (1,1)$?  In each case, the answer is row-reduction.